# c#.net 32 bit application Not working on 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, installation, setup-project

I am new to .NET application.

I have developed the application on 32 bit OS with Visual Studio 2008.

The application required the Microsoft.Interop services and for PDF services to open PDF files and MS Office files.

It also required SQL Express for database operations.

The application works fine on 32bit OS.

Then I created the setup for 64 bit OS, I added a new Setup project with wizard in Visual 
Studio 2010 and select the Primary output and Localized resources.

But it does not included the Resources folder to the Application folder.

I set the target machine 64x and build the project, also before building give the prerequisites to the project which is Windows Installer 3.1, and .net framework 4.0, I have used the .net framwork 3.5 in the application.

Then I ran the setup, which executed successfully.
But when I tried to run the application it gave the message "Application has stoped working. Finding for the solution from the web.." and it closed.

Then I saw that there was no resources folder so I just copied the resources folder to the application where it was installed. Then the application worked fine.

So I created the setup again but this time I also provided the Resources folder to the application folder. Built the Setup and tried to run the application but the same message is prompted to me as it was giving before "Application has stopped working...", so I looked for the resource folder and all the required files which were there.

Comment: Check if the build-action for the ressources differs in x64-mode and if you are deploying to the correct target path.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a separate 64-bit version makes no sense in your case.

You have dependencies to 32-bit components; as a consequence, all<sup>1</sup> your assemblies **must** be compiled to the **x86 target platform** and be installed using a 32-bit MSI.

If you get an "Application has stopped working..." error, this indicates that an exception occurred that has not been handled by your process. You can get the stack trace e.g. from the event log.

<sub><sup>1</sup> In fact, at the least the entry assembly must have an x86 target platform, and all other assemblies must have either an x86 or AnyCPU target platform.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Check you have changed the platform target to x64 or AnyCPU in your project -> Build Properties

Comment: This makes no sense. A platform target of x64 or AnyCPU actually is probably the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

hey friends thanks for answering my question. Finally doing a lot of things I found that it was converting the sql database to 2008 while creating the setup. And I was setting the sql express 2005 on the client machine. Then I changed the sql server 2005 to sql express 2008 and run the setup. Then I found that at the first time the exe required all the rights to convert so I tried the setup Run as Administrator and bingo the setup works for 2 different pc..
The only thing is required that at first time I need to run the application as Administrator.
Thanks for help I